# How to connect windows phone 8 to database and apply azure sync data to it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, azure, windows-phone-8

What is the best possible way to connect your windows phone 8 application with the database?Which is the best option? I want to make synchronization possible to that app database and azure SQL database.So the ultimate goal is to update the azure database and view the output on phone app even while it is offline. 
Provide appropriate links & tutorial wherever possible.

Comment: You want a service that is providing that data. IE: Don't connect to your DB directly. Then you query your service, and you service handles the caching of data/etc. If the server is unreachable, then you store the last sync on the device in local storage and pull from that.

Comment: Can you provide any tutorial or document related to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an ASP.NET MVC WebAPI server, hosted as an Azure website, which connects to your database. Then the Windows Phone can talk to the server using a RESTFUL interface, ie JSON carried by HTTP.

Store data on the phone in local storage. I really would not try to run a database on Windows Phone.

See Microsoft ASP.NET Web API > Overview and Getting Started: http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos/getting-started

Wikipedia > Representational state transfer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

MSDN > HttpClient Class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx